# Elasticseach query optimization

Tags: optimization, elasticsearch

Is there any way to optimize query in Elasticsearch? I am using below query. Its taking average `15-20s` and sometimes it little bit fast `4-5s`.

My server configuration  :- Centos 6.3, 8 Core 16GB RAM

```
{
"fields": [
  "_id",
  "aff_id",
  "post_uri",
  "blog_cat",
  "cat_score",
  "secondary_cat",
  "secondary_cat_score",
  "title",
  "_score"
],
"min_score": 0.0134,
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
              "fields": [
                 "title"
              ],
              "query": "Archery OR Athletics OR Badminton OR Basketball OR Beach Volleyball OR Boxing OR Canoe Slalom OR Canoe Sprint OR Cycling BMX OR Cycling Mountain Bike OR Cycling Road OR Cycling Track OR Diving OR Equestrian / Dressage OR Equestrian / Eventing OR Equestrian / Jumping OR Fencing OR Football OR Golf OR Gymnastics Artistic"
           }
        }
     ],
     "must_not": [],
     "should": []
   }
}
```

I read article regarding Elasticsearch query optimization

https://speakerdeck.com/elasticsearch/query-optimization-go-more-faster-better

Tried solution change query like below but doesn't get any difference.

```
    {
   "fields": [
        "aff_id",
        "post_uri",
        "blog_cat",
        "cat_score",
        "secondary_cat",
        "secondary_cat_score",
        "title"
   ],
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "url.cat": "sports"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "main_cat.sports": {
                           "gte": ".15"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "query": {
               "query_string": {
                  "fields": [
                     "body",
                     "title"
                  ],
                  "query": "Archery OR Athletics OR Badminton OR Basketball OR Beach Volleyball OR Boxing OR Canoe Slalom OR Canoe Sprint OR Cycling BMX OR Cycling Mountain Bike OR Cycling Road OR Cycling Track OR Diving OR Equestrian / Dressage OR Equestrian / Eventing OR Equestrian / Jumping OR Fencing OR Football OR Golf OR Gymnastics Artistic"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "from": 0,
   "size": 1000
}
```

**Note :** I am using default analyzer I haven't defined custom analyzer.

Comment: Did you try remove `fields` section in your query ? How many records currently in your index ? What's your analyzers & mapping definition ?

Comment: Yes also I have tried remove `fields` section. and approx `212,00,000` records in my index.

Comment: `mappings` is the mappings defined at index creation time, can you post it ? BTW, 200M records is a big number to consider compare to your machine config (just 16GB RAM). You can also check the size of your index and post it here. I usually rent a 64GB RAM for my index (50GB indexed data)

Comment: My index size is 110GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is optimize version of query :-

Changes:-

1) Use `filters` in query, `filter` are cached.
2) The `query_string/query` filter is not cached by default but we can turn it on by setting `_cache: true`.

```
{
   "fields": [
        "aff_id",
        "post_uri",
        "blog_cat",
        "cat_score",
        "secondary_cat",
        "secondary_cat_score",
        "title"
   ],
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "url.cat": "sports"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "main_cat.sports": {
                           "gte": ".15"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "fquery": {
                        "query": {
                           "query_string": {
                              "fields": [
                                 "body",
                                 "title"
                              ],
                              "query": "Archery OR Athletics OR Badminton OR Basketball OR Beach Volleyball OR Boxing OR Canoe Slalom OR Canoe Sprint OR Cycling BMX OR Cycling Mountain Bike OR Cycling Road OR Cycling Track OR Diving OR Equestrian / Dressage OR Equestrian / Eventing OR Equestrian / Jumping OR Fencing OR Football OR Golf OR Gymnastics Artisti"
                           }
                        },
                        "_cache": true
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "from": 0,
   "size": 1000,
   "sort": [
      {
         "_uid": "desc"
      }
      ]
}
```